# How to prevent your fields name in your form.py, to display on your form after using 'as_cripsy_field' on your template

Tags: django, django-templates, bootstrap-5, django-crispy-forms

How do i stop my  fields name in my form.py, from displaying as a label on my form after using  **as_cripsy_field** on my template in an input field.

**example**:

```
{{form.fieldname|as_cripsy_field}}
```

Comment: can you please share your forms.py

Answer (score 0):

You can use `helper attributes`

To remove all fields label you can set `form_show_labels` to False in the `init()` method. By default it is set to True.

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

To remove field label for certain specific field you can use

```
self.fields['your_field_name'].label = False
```